# How can I define a Google_Service_Drive variable correctly with Google Drive API using PHP to create a folder?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm newbie on this, so I hope you could help me, I'm checking the [Google Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) because I want to create a folder in Google Drive using PHP, I'm using the code example but I notice that I must define this "$driveService" variable first.

I must say I made the previous steps before (Create a project, install via composer, generate my client_secret.json file, etc).

So I tried to use the example writing this code:

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('64*****-client_secret.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

 $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
   'name' => 'TEST',
   'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));

 $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

 printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);

?>
```

But when I execute the page it shows nothing in the browser, it shows this in terminal:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with 
 message '{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "required",
   "message": "Login Required",
   "locationType": "header",
   "location": "Authorization"
  }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
' in /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() in /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

I also added these lines:

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('64*****-client_secret.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
```

But it's still the same, I can't create the folder and get the folder ID. How can I fix it?

I'll appreciate your answer.

Comment: You need to authenticate with a user in order to perform and Gdrive action. See the quickstart https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I made the quickstart before, It worked, so I replaced the client part with the getClient function and now it shows me `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"   }  ],  "code": 403,  "message": "Insufficient Permission" }}'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the access token first; the user needs to grant you access to his or her drive file through the user consent screen.
Yo can try this;

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('64*****-client_secret.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

         /** checks if the access token has previously been obtained and sets it **/
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']){
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
     //what ever code you want to run
      else{
     //redirects the user to authenticate
  $redirect_uri = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/drive/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    }
```

The  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json'); you added is a repetition and not necessary. Also remember to call session start at the beginning of the code like this:session_start();

For detail check out: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer